# Recursion with test case

Tags: recursion

I am trying to code following recursion problem. Every time I run the test case it gives me out of bound error on the else if line. How do I fix the out of bound error. under the code is the test case.

```
static boolean allEqual(int[] a, int start, int end) {

 if( a[start + 1]>=a.length){return false;}   
 if (start == end && a[start] == a[end]) {
        return true;
    }
    ///recursive
    else if (a[start] == a[start + 1]) // Error over here 
{  
        return allEqual(a, start + 1, end);
    }
    // else if (start == end && a[start] == a[end]) {
    //   return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
// Following is the test case
    Random rng = new Random(SEED);
    for(int i = 0; i < RUNS; i++) {
        int[] a = new int[i];
        int v = rng.nextInt();
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            a[j] = v;
        }
        assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, 0, i-1));
        for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, j, i-1));
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, 0, j));
            a[j] = a[j] - 1;
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, 0, j-1));
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, j + 1, i-1));
            assertFalse(rp.allEqual(a, 0, i-1));
            a[j] = a[j] + 2;
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, 0, j-1));
            assertTrue(rp.allEqual(a, j + 1, i-1));
            assertFalse(rp.allEqual(a, 0, i-1));
            a[j] = a[j] - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you restrict `start + 1` to not be greater than or equals to `a.length` ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem. But if the start index equals  the end index, isn't a[start] == a[end] always true?

Comment: if( a[start + 1]>=a.length){return false;} I tried inserting this right after method declaration but still having same issue

Comment: Bart when the start counter increases eventually it reaches the end index. so i am just checking the value at that point.

Comment: `if( a[start + 1]>=a.length){return false;}` is this actually what you want to try? You're here checking if the value of a[start+1] is greater than or equal to a.length, might be that you want to check if `start+1 >= a.length`

Comment: Kolsyrad that worked. the idea was that if start+1>a.length then return true.